# Why do I get the following error from dart when I try to use inheritence?

Tags: inheritance, dart

When I run:

```
#import('package:logging/logging.dart');

class Trace extends Logger {
    Trace(String name) : super(name);
}
```

dart says:

```
'file:///home/jim/Code/dart/trace/Trace.dart': Error: line 6 pos 26: super class constructor 'Logger.' not found
    Trace(String name) : super(name);
```

I'm following the example in the technical overview:

```
class Square extends Rectangle {
  Square(num size) : super(size, size);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Logger`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/logging/Logger.html) class does not have any constructors. It has factories.

You tried to create a class that extends [`Logger`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/logging/Logger.html) and specified a default constructor that tried to call [`Logger`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/logging/Logger.html)'s default constructor, which does not exist.

Maybe you were looking for something like this:

```dart
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';

class Trace extends Logger {
  factory Trace(String name) {
    return new Logger(name);
  }
}

main() {
  var i = new Trace('foo');

  i.on.record.add((LogRecord record) {
    print(record.message);
  });

  i.severe('blaa!');
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to read further to understand what the difference is. Seems like I'm prevented from cleanly extending this class. Yuck! This reminds me of java :(

Comment: This wouldn't work as of now; the factory constructor should return a sub-type of the class, not a super-type.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you try to extend a class (`Logger`) that has only a factory constructor. As suggested on the thread [abstract classes and factory constructors](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/misc/o-4rK9OLcIs) you should consider implementing `Logger` instead of extending it.

Comment: Hopefully I can do this without having to implement every method. Why make it a class if I can't extend it? Sigh...